# InsertCommand in code behind giving error

Tags: vb.net, sql-insert, detailsview

This may be a very silly error, but gridview's states and when exactly one occurs/changes always gets me mixed up.

I have a detailsview that works as an input. There is a "New" button in the footer which puts the dv in insertmode. I want to perform input checking so the asp:sqldatasource in the aspx page is minimal and the checking is done in the code behind. One path the method can take constructs the insertcommand, adds parameters as needed, and adds and entry to the database, but the other path simply gives an error message to a label and ends the method. I get a debugger popup in IE when this path happens saying "Inserting is not supported by datasource [datasource] unless insertcommand is specified"

DetailsView:

```
    <asp:DetailsView ID="dvInsertInterrupt" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="false" DataSourceID="sqldsInsertInterrupt" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <Fields>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer" InsertVisible="true" HeaderStyle-CssClass="col-xs-3 field-label active">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNames" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqldsNames" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="AccountNumber" CssClass="col-md-9 form-control" />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start Date" InsertVisible="true" HeaderStyle-CssClass="col-xs-3 field-label active">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:Calendar ID="calStartDate" runat="server" CssClas="col-md-9 form-control" />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start Time" InsertVisible="true" HeaderStyle-CssClass="col-xs-3 field-label active">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartTime" runat="server" MaxLength="4" /><asp:Label ID="lblInfo" runat="server"><small> 24-Hour Format</small></asp:Label>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Duration" InsertVisible="true" HeaderStyle-CssClass="col-xs-3 field-label active">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlHours" runat="server" CssClass="col-md-9 form-control">
    <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="5" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="6" Value="6" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="7" Value="7" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="8" Value="8" Selected="True" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false" HeaderStyle-CssClass="field-label col-xs-3 active">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbNew" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="New" Text="New Interrupt" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbInsert" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
</InsertItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
```

DataSource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqldsInsertInterrupt" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WebTestConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Interrupt" InsertCommand="" />
```

Code Behind Method:

```
Protected Sub dvInsertInterrupt_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DetailsViewCommandEventArgs) Handles dvInsertInterrupt.ItemCommand
        Try
            If e.CommandName = "Insert" Then
                Dim accountNumber As Integer = DirectCast(dvInsertInterrupt.Rows(0).Cells(1).Controls(1), DropDownList).SelectedValue
                Dim startDate As DateTime = DirectCast(dvInsertInterrupt.Rows(1).Cells(1).Controls(1), Calendar).SelectedDate
                Dim milTime As String = DirectCast(dvInsertInterrupt.Rows(2).Cells(1).Controls(1), TextBox).Text
                Dim hr As Integer = 0
                Dim min As Integer = 0
                Dim start As DateTime
                Dim hours As Integer = DirectCast(dvInsertInterrupt.Rows(3).Cells(1).Controls(1), DropDownList).SelectedValue
                Dim endDate As DateTime
                Dim message As String = ""

                If IsNumeric(milTime) Then
                    If milTime.Length < 4 Then
                        Select Case milTime.Length
                            Case Is < 2
                                milTime = "000" & milTime.ToString
                            Case Is < 3
                                milTime = "00" & milTime.ToString
                            Case Else
                                milTime = "0" & milTime.ToString
                        End Select
                        hr = Left(milTime, 2)
                        min = Right(milTime, 2)
                    Else
                        hr = Left(milTime, 2)
                        min = Right(milTime, 2)
                    End If

                    If hr < 0 Or hr > 23 Then
                        message = "Hour must be between 0 and 23"
                        DirectCast(dvInsertInterrupt.Rows(2).Cells(1).Controls(1), TextBox).Text = ""
                    Else
                        If min < 0 Or min > 59 Then
                            message = "Minutes must be between 0 and 59"
                            DirectCast(dvInsertInterrupt.Rows(2).Cells(1).Controls(1), TextBox).Text = ""
                        Else
                            start = New DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, startDate.Day, hr, min, 0)
                            endDate = start.AddHours(hours)
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    message = "Enter numeric values only"
                    DirectCast(dvInsertInterrupt.Rows(2).Cells(1).Controls(1), TextBox).Text = ""
                End If

                If Not CheckForInterrupt(accountNumber, start, endDate) Then
                    sqldsInsertInterrupt.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO Interrupt (CustomerAccountNumber, StartDate, Hours, EndDate, Approved, SecondNotificationSent) VALUES (@accountNumber, @startDate, @hours, @endDate, 0, 0)"
                    sqldsInsertInterrupt.InsertParameters.Add("accountNumber", accountNumber)
                    sqldsInsertInterrupt.InsertParameters.Add("startDate", start)
                    sqldsInsertInterrupt.InsertParameters.Add("hours", hours)
                    sqldsInsertInterrupt.InsertParameters.Add("endDate", endDate)
                Else
                    lblInsertMessage.Text = "There is already an interrupt scheduled at that time!"

                End If

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            lblInsertMessage.Text = "**Error** - " & ex.ToString & " **"
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: May be set your command here `SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Interrupt" InsertCommand="????????" />` and add parameter values later. May be you run something before it is set. Basically, bad timing. Hard to understand as is

Comment: I'm sorry for the messy code, but if I put the INSERT statement in the aspx code then it wouldn't go through the input validation in the code behind would it? It would just take the inputs as is and attempt to INSERT INTO the db

Comment: No, this is not about code being messy. It is about coding in the right location in sequence of calls. If you place your `INSERT . . .(@..., @...` upfront. Your SqlDataSource has events [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx]. **Inserting - Occurs before an insert operation**. So, in this event place your code to set parameters and values. See what happens. It seems you just not having your code in the right event.